# Reusable vector module with tests

Tags: unit-testing, rust, coordinate-system, modules

I'm learning rust with mostly a background in managed languages. I have a little C background.

As a learning project I am re-implementing a linear-transformations     library I've been working on in C#.

This is my first reusable library I've tried to make in Rust and I'd like feedback on creating and using modules, as well as rust programming in general.

Project structure

```
+ transforms
    + src
        - lib.rs
        - tests.rs
        - transforms.rs
        - vectors.rs
    + target
    - Cargo.toml
```

I haven't made any changes to the automatic `cargo.toml`.
`transforms.rs` is empty and have the linear transformation code added to it in the future.

**lib.rs**

```
pub mod vectors;
mod tests; // tests don't get run if I don't have this, not sure why?
```

**vectors.rs**

```
use std::fmt;

pub struct KVector3{
    pub x : f64,
    pub y : f64,
    pub z : f64,
}

pub trait Vector {
    fn magnitude_squared(&self) -> f64;
    fn magnitude(&self) -> f64;        
}

pub trait Vector3 {
    fn dot(&self, v : KVector3) -> f64;
    fn cross(&self, v : KVector3) -> KVector3;

    fn zero() -> KVector3;
    fn i_hat() -> KVector3;
    fn j_hat() -> KVector3;
    fn k_hat() -> KVector3;
}

impl Vector for KVector3 {
    fn magnitude_squared(&self) -> f64 {
        self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y + self.z * self.z
    }

    fn magnitude(&self) -> f64 {
        (self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y + self.z * self.z).sqrt()
    }    
}

impl Vector3 for KVector3 {
    fn dot(&self, v : KVector3) -> f64 {
        self.x * v.x + self.y * v.y + self.z + v.z
    }

    fn cross(&self, v : KVector3) -> KVector3 {
        KVector3 {
            x : self.y * v.z - self.z * v.y,
            y : self.x * v.z - self.z * v.x,
            z : self.x * v.y - self.y * v.x
        }
    }

    fn zero() -> KVector3 { KVector3 { x: 0., y: 0., z: 0. } }

    fn i_hat() -> KVector3 { KVector3 { x: 1., y: 0., z: 0. } }

    fn j_hat() -> KVector3 { KVector3 { x: 0., y: 1., z: 0. } }

    fn k_hat() -> KVector3 { KVector3 { x: 0., y: 0., z: 1. } }
}


impl PartialEq<KVector3> for KVector3 {
    fn eq(&self, other : &KVector3) -> bool {
        self.x == other.x && self.y == other.y && self.z == other.z
    }
}

impl fmt::Debug for KVector3 {
    fn fmt(&self, f : &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "<{},{},{}>", self.x, self.y, self.z)
    }
}
```

**tests.rs**

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {    

    use ::vectors::{Vector, Vector3, KVector3};

    #[test]
    fn unit_magnitude_squared() {
        let mag_squared = KVector3::i_hat().magnitude_squared();
        assert_eq!(1., mag_squared);
    }

    #[test]
    fn v3_magnitude_squared() {
        let triangle = KVector3 { x : 3., y : 4., z: 0. };
        let mag_squared = triangle.magnitude_squared();
        assert_eq!(25., mag_squared);
    }

    #[test]
    fn v3_magnitude() {
        let triangle = KVector3 { x : 3., y : 4., z: 0. };
        let mag = triangle.magnitude();
        assert_eq!(5., mag);
    }

    #[test]
    fn cross_product() {        
        let product = KVector3::i_hat().cross(KVector3::j_hat());
        assert_eq!(KVector3::k_hat(), product);

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/194566/revisions) so that it is more specific about this code. Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

## Unit tests should be put in the file they're testing

It's [recommended to put the unit tests into the same file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch11-03-test-organization.html) as the functions you're testing. This prevents your code from getting out of sync with your tests more easily. Also, you don't want one single large `tests.rs`for all your unit tests.

## Use proper types in traits

At the moment, as soon as we use any function from `Vector3`, we end up with a `KVector3`:

```
pub trait Vector3 {
    fn dot(&self, v : KVector3) -> f64;
    fn cross(&self, v : KVector3) -> KVector3; // here

    fn zero() -> KVector3;  // here
    fn i_hat() -> KVector3; // here
    fn j_hat() -> KVector3; // here
    fn k_hat() -> KVector3; // here
}
```

That's probably not what you intended. Use `Self` instead here. Furthermore, all your functions are fixed to `f64`, but one can implement all functions from `Vector3` for *any* number type. The following interface encapsulates that:

```
pub trait Vector3 {
    type Output;

    fn dot(&self, v: Self) -> Self::Output;
    fn cross(&self, v: Self) -> Self;

    fn zero() -> Self;
    fn i_hat() -> Self;
    fn j_hat() -> Self;
    fn k_hat() -> Self;
}
```

## Use `derive` for canonical implementations

If you use `#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]` you don't have to implement both variants yourself.

## Consider generics for your structs (and traits)

Your `KVector3` only supports `f64`. However, we can imagine a situation where we want to store `f32`, for [example for GPU calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079906/float-vs-double-on-graphics-hardware). We can use `KVector3` also in that circumstance if we make it generic.

## Add documentation and examples

Since you're working on a *reusable* library you want to have some documentation at hand. Furthermore, [examples in your documentation are automatically checked with `cargo test`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch14-02-publishing-to-crates-io.html#making-useful-documentation-comments).